# Password reset link was delivered via text not email, how and why? Any insight is appreciated

Tags: passwords, malware, attacks, man-in-the-middle, mobile

I think my smartphone is being hacked into + controlled by a third party, possibly my internet connection as well. Some very odd things have been ongoing for many months. On my phone I hear constant clicks while I'm in conversation, others have heard them too, my data is being used up though not by me, when my phone powers down it takes about 10 seconds or so to turn off and the screen turns a hue of blue before it shuts off, the other day I heard someone talking for a split second, and today I requested a password reset for one of my accounts and instead of the link being sent to the email associated with said account, it was sent to my cellphone via a text message that contained a link. Which I didn't click. The email account is not linked to the smartphone I currently have, but was previously connected to my old phone. I had the same cellphone provider for both.

With my home internet, I've gotten some error messages and many redirects as of late. In general there is also one woman who answers the calls I make to various companies. I've come to know her voice quite well.

Any insight as to to hows and why's and suggestions you have for what I can do to protect my privacy via phone and internet is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if the old email account is something like yourphonenumber@mobile.att.net,  its a direct email address to the text msg in/out box. Watch what you buy, some phone manufacturers have skipped some of the android updates so of the phones out there have security vulnerabilities. Here is some articles I searched on this : https://www.engadget.com/2018/04/12/researchers-some-android-phone-makers-hide-missed-updates/  and https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/apr/13/android-phone-makers-skip-security-updates-users-smartphone-software-google

Comment: I probably wipe the phone and do any updates, otherwise I would go back to a flip phone if you are not really doing anything with it.

Comment: None of your details indicates a security problem. There are just too many possibilities for us to make a diagnosis. You also do not give us any technical details for us to work with, like how old the phone is, what kind it is, etc. But even if you did provide those details, this is no the place to ask these types of technical support questions.